# Recover a running script from a terminal session

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnu-screen

So I'm using [GNU Screen](http://aperiodic.net/screen/) to manage multiple running scripts/programs. The multiplexing & detachability is quite helpful.

I removed a script from disk and now I'm having some trouble finding the backup. However, one of the terminal sessions was executing the script before the file was deleted and it continues to work just fine.

**Is there a way to hijack the terminal session that is currently running the script to recover the contents of this file?**

Comment: Also: [How to recover deleted file if it is still opened by some process? - SU](https://superuser.com/q/283102/334516), [Relinking a deleted file](https://serverfault.com/q/168909/229499)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

look for the script's pid using `ps`

```
ps -ef|grep script.sh
Fdo  8983  8463  0 12:28 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./script.sh
```

check `/proc/$PID/fd/`; there should be a broken link to the script file, but `cat` *should* work (while the script is running!):

```
cat /proc/8983/fd/255 
#!/bin/bash
# script contents!
```

good luck!

Comment: @mrc I think that work, because the content of files, is loaded in memory

Comment: Great suggestion!  Its also a warning that @fdo needs to set up a decent backup routine, because next time he may not be so lucky.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Nothing to do with it being loaded in memory or not. Linux explicitly won't remove a file (inode) while there are open handles - the file remains on the disk, taking up space. `rm` and other tools *unlink* the file, removing the link from the file *name* to the actual data (referenced by inode), but as long as a reference exists (hard link or open handle) the inode is not deleted.

Comment: Just curious... how did you know to check fd 255? Or is that just an example?

Comment: @gardenhead It's an example.

Comment: @gardenhead, I checked on my machine with a simple script ...

Comment: This only works if the script was deleted, not if the script was overwritten with rubbish.